# Construction of Omega Network

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing, computer-networks

I understand that we could draw N * N Omega Network, 
But can we draw an Omega Network to connect 6 CPUs to 4 memories? (The number of CPUs does not equal the number of memories)

Comment: Are the number "6" and "4" of any relevance or are they simply an example?

Comment: just an example for different numbers of CPUs and Memories

Comment: Omega network seems to be defined for $2^n$ nodes on either side.

Comment: So we can't draw such a network, thank you @YuvalFilmus